# Is this a bug with array_search?

Tags: php

```
 if(array_search('test',array('0'=>'test'))){
    echo 'test';
}
```

Isn't echoing anything. But:

```
if(array_search('test',array('0'=>'random', '1'=>'test'))){
    echo 'test';
}
```

Echoes test?

Comment: array_search return 0 in the first case, which is not true.

Comment: I think you need to read the [documentation for `array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), in particular the section about what it returns...

Comment: just remove the indexes and put the array like `array('test');`

Comment: If you want to test for not-found, use `array_search( ... ) === false`. Otherwise if you get a match on the first item of the array, you'll get integer zero, which evaluates to not-true if you are not also checking its type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_search()` is returning `0`, which (in a non-strict comparison) is `false`:

```
var_dump(array_search('test',array('0'=>'test'))); // int(0)
var_dump(array_search('test',array('0'=>'random', '1'=>'test'))); // int(1)
```

Use [`!== false` (as the docs suggest)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) instead:

```
if(array_search('test',array('0'=>'test')) !== false){
    echo '1 ';
}
if(array_search('test',array('0'=>'random', '1'=>'test')) !== false){
    echo '2 ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (in_array) function to check if var in array or not

like this:

```
if(in_array('test',array('0'=>'random', '1'=>'test'))){
echo 'exist';
}
```